# Difference of dependent uniform random variables

Tags: density-function, uniform-distribution

My question is similar to [the one posed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423277/calculating-the-sum-of-dependent-uniform-random-variables?newreg=8ec140e045ce4c3cb94fd0c3a7ceaec3) for a sum of dependent uniform RVs.

How can I find the CDF of $T=X-aY$, where $X\sim U[0,B]$, $Y\sim U[0,X]$, and $a<1$ is a constant. I've tried replicating the results in the link above but it does not match my simulations. My guess is that I am incorrectly deriving the bounds of integration.

Comment: Please show us your calculation, then.